# How to show / hide multiple elements at the same time with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

So, I have this between my head tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">
hidden_links = document.getElementsByName("javascript_needed");
    for (i = 0; i < hidden_links.length; i++) {
        hidden_links[i].style.display = "visible";
    }
</script>
```

And my divs are all similar to

```
    <div name="javascript_needed" style="display: none;">stuff</div>
```

the overall goal here, is to have these divs hide when javascript is disabled, and re-enable them when javascript is enabled.... but for whatever reason, my code doesn't work. I ever tried it in the webkit console, and nothing errored =\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JavaScript is executed before the divs are in the DOM. The standard way to do something after the DOM is ready is to use jQuery's `$(document).ready(function () { });`, but there are other ways as well.

The oldschool way is to use `<body onload="myfunction()">`.

Here's a newer way (**edit:** put `display:none` into CSS):

HTML:

```
<p class='javascript_needed'>hello</p>​
```

CSS:

```
.javascript_needed {display:none;}
```

JavaScript:

```
​$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.javascript_needed').show();
});
​
```

Comment: Read the question: when javascript is disabled ^)

Comment: @VMATm - I did. The divs are hidden with `display:none` when JavaScript is disabled. The JavaScript is there to set display to visible.

Comment: Rather than use an inline `onload` handler, you can unobtrusively do `window.onload = function() { ... }` in your JS.

Comment: brilliant! 
the webkit debugger should try to mention that... like... "unexecutable code" or something like that..

Comment: @DerNalia the code executes just fine, but the array returned from `getElementsByName` will be empty. Also do take a look at my answer, it might be a slightly cleaner way to accomplish this goal.

Answer (score 1):

Your JS should be setting the div's display to "block" ("visible" isn't a valid value for display).

Also, from the looks of things your elements aren't in the DOM at the time the code is fired (your code doesn't see them yet).  Do any of the following:

**Place your code anywhere in the document body below the divs**

**or, use an unobtrusive strategy to fire your function on window load, a la:**

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(nameOfSomeFunctionToRunOnPageLoad);
```

**or, Use a JS framework's "ready" functionality, a la jQuery's**:

```
$(function () {
    nameOfSomeFunctionToRunOnPageLoad();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"visible" is not a valid value for "display". You're after "inline" or "block".

"visible" and "hidden" are valid values for the "visibility" CSS property.

Comment: `display:none` removes the object from the flow, whereas `visibility:hidden` leaves the object in the flow but you can't see it. It depends whether you want to leave gaps or not.

Comment: but, changing "visible" to block in the JS doesnt work... 
I don't even think the JS is executing...
shouldn't it execute when its loaded? cause its in the head tags?

Comment: @DerNalia: If your JavaScript isn't wrapped in any `onload` function, it will run before the DOM is loaded. If you do `alert(document.getElementsByName("javascript_needed").length)`, you can see what elements are matching it. If it's "0", you need to wait for the DOM to load.

Answer (score 0):

**Difference between `display` and `visible`:**

- An element that is `visible` still takes up space on the page. The adjacent content is not rearranged when the element is toggled between `visible` and `hidden`.
- An element that is `display=none` will not take up any space on the page. Other `display` values will cause the element to take up space. For example, `display=block` not only displays the element, but adds line breaks before and after it.

Answer (score 0):

The disadvantage of showing elements on ready is that they will only flicker in after the page has finished loading. This usually looks odd.

Here's what I usually do. In a script in the `<head>` of the document (which runs before the body begins to render), do this:

```
document.documentElement.className = "JS";
```

Then, any CSS selectors that descend from `.JS` will only match if JavaScript is enabled. Let's say you give your links a class of `javascriptNeeded` (a class is more appropriate than a name here). Add this to your CSS:

```
.javascriptNeeded{
 display: none;
}
.JS .javascriptNeeded{

 display: inline;
}
```

…and the elements will be there from the start, but only if JavaScript is enabled.

Comment: According to jQuery docs: "Everything that you stick inside its brackets is ready to go at the earliest possible moment — as soon as the DOM is registered by the browser, which allows for some nice hiding and showing effects and other stuff immediately when the user first sees the page elements." `http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()`

Comment: @Skilldrick: Yes, but the "earliest possible moment" is still *after* the page has been rendered to the screen. There will be a flicker.