# How can I use CSS to show and hide multiple elements at once?

Tags: javascript, css, hide, show

I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023767/how-to-show-hide-multiple-elements-at-the-same-time-with-javascript) that *looked* like exactly what I wanted, but I can't seem to get it to work at all.  Since it is well over a year old, I thought perhaps something may have changed, or that there might be a simpler way to do it by now.

That is to say, I cannot get the method I linked above to work.  I copied and pasted exactly, and used `<body onLoad="javascript_needed()">` because I wasn't sure where `$(document).ready(function ()...` was supposed to go.  I am, sadly, quite unfamiliar with Javascript.

Comment: Can you post your html so we can see what's going on?

Comment: Are you including the jQuery library on the page? http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this;

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    //Code goes in here.
  });

</script>
```

Don't forget to load the jQuery library at the same time from http://jquery.com/

Also, you are going to want to read up on selectors.

Using `$("#myElement")` will select elements that have an id of "myElement".

Using `$(".myElement")` will select elements that have a class of "myElement".

So;

```
<div class="hideMe">Content</div>
<div class="hideMe">Content</div>
<div class="hideMe">Content</div>
<div class="doNotHideMe">Content</div>

<input type="button" class="ClickMe" value="click me"/>

<script>

  $(function(){
    $(".ClickMe").click(function(){
      $(".hideMe").hide(250);
    });
  });

</script>
```

**edit**

If you want to link to the jquery library online then use;

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you download the library and insert the js file into your project then use;

```
<script src="/yourPathToTheLibrary/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I really am unfamiliar with all things java.  How do I make sure I load the JQuery library?

Comment: Oh and make sure the link is either in your master page if you have one, or at the top of the page before your javascript code.

Comment: @Jerry Rowe, JavaScript really has nothing to do with Java.  It is a separate language altogether. It is based on ECMAScript.  At the core, JS is really closer to Scheme.  A book I read described it as `Scheme in C's clothing`.

Comment: I just spent some hours reading up on javascript and stuff.  What you said about selectors was THE thing I needed to see.  The . instead of the # made the difference for me.  ++ for you!! Your links and stuff were very helpful, and this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The `$` syntax is all part of jQuery.  If you wish to use jQuery then somewhere in your code, use a script tag as in your post:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.selector').hide(250);
    });
</script>
```

If you want pure JavaScript, then there is a little more overhead.  Not including the document ready stuff (which can be a lot of extra code to do it right...See example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989095/javascripthow-to-write-document-ready-like-event-without-jquery)).

```
<script>
    elements = document.querySelectorAll('.selector');

    for(int i=0,len=elements.length;i<len;++i) {
        elements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

You can put that in a function if you would like.  To show the elements set the display attribute to `''`.